# Why is my code showing up twice on my website?

Tags: javascript, eventbrite

I am new here and a massive noob when it comes to coding. I have been teaching myself some basics, but I cannot seem to figure this one out.

I'm trying to integrate this piece of code in my website. It is an automaticcaly genenerated code from Eventbrite. Somehow it the whole thing is showing op twice in the front end of my website. I am using Divi builder with the code module. I hope someone can help. I have been googling around for over an hour now but I can't seem to find a fix.

```
<div id="eventbrite-widget-container-107705263342"></div>

<script src="https://www.eventbrite.nl/static/widgets/eb_widgets.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var exampleCallback = function() {
        console.log('Order complete!');
    };

    window.EBWidgets.createWidget({
        // Required
        widgetType: 'checkout',
        eventId: '107705263342',
        iframeContainerId: 'eventbrite-widget-container-107705263342',

        // Optional
        iframeContainerHeight: 425,  // Widget height in pixels. Defaults to a minimum of 425px if not provided
        onOrderComplete: exampleCallback  // Method called when an order has successfully completed
    });
</script>
```

Comment: OK, I managed to fix it by placing the code in a text module rather than a code module. That seems to do the trick!